# Rscript called from PHP does not shows tildes/accents

Tags: php, r, encoding, plot, tilde

I have an script in `R` named `myplots.R`, that produce a few plots (graphs, etc).

If I call this script with Rscript from the Linux SHELL:

```
Rscript myplots.R
```

It create my plots correctly, showing accents, tildes, special chars, etc.

Then, in PHP I call to:

```
$a=shell_exec("/usr/bin/Rscript myplots.R");
```

It's working, but accents/tildes, special chars, etc are showed like

[image]

Where it must be:

(Predicción -

PHP file that call to shell_exec has:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

and all my files in R use:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "es_ES.utf8")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean that the values aren't shown. Are you printing the content of "$a" into the page or something? Does the R script itself actually run? Are you just having a problem with the HTML generated by  PHP? Are these values in the images themselves?

Comment: Not showed correctly. For instance, this character ñ is changed to ..